I'm getting an Error with my iff statement
I have a query for a report. One of the fields in the report I need to count the number of cases carried forward to the next year because they were not closed the previous year.
My query is made up of three tables.  The column I get #error I have the following written
Carryfoward:Iff([dateReceived]<[forms]![Form_Report]![textStartDate]) AND (IsNull([DispositionDate])),1,0)

The field DispositionDate is in Table_Disposition
Carryfoward:Iff([dateReceived]<[forms]![Form_Report]![textStartDate]) AND (IsNull([DispositionDate])),1,0)  

I expected to get a number.  When I run the query from the form, I get a popup that wants me to Enter Parameter Value for CarryForward.   When I run the query from the query, I get #error in the CarryForward colunm.

Try using IIf:
Carryfoward: IIf([dateReceived]<[forms]![Form_Report]![textStartDate] AND IsNull([DispositionDate]),1,0)

or alternatively:
Carryfoward: Abs([dateReceived]<[forms]![Form_Report]![textStartDate] AND [DispositionDate] Is Null)


I tried using both of your suggestions and still get the same error. When I use your suggestions in a new test query using just table_Disoposition it works. When I add a 2nd table to the query is when I get the error.

Then you probably don't have the syntax for joining tables right.

You are correct. I changed the joining properties and your suggestion worked great. Thank you.

Great! Then please mark as answered.
